# Deriving a quadratic function from a description of it

Tags: functions, quadratics

> [image]

I have honestly no clue how to proceed with the above task. I know that the vertex is the lowest point of the graph, and by looking at this graph I'm assuming that the vertex is at the middle of it, which is when x = 10. I also know that *r* and *s* are the x and y coordinates of the vertex. I also know a bunch of other stuff like r = -b/2a, p+q = -b/a, p*q = c/a, but I have no idea how to begin solving this.

I tried by replacing r by 10 and s by 1, but then I still have x and a which are unknown so I don't know what to do afterwards.

Maybe some of you can help guide me by asking me a leading question or something? If someone is willing to help me demistify all the random knowledge that I have on functions and maybe help me connect all the pieces together, I'd be very very grateful!

Comment: The vertex form of a quadratic function is $f(x)=a(x-r)^2+s$ where $(r,s)$ is the vertex. You know the vertex is $(10,1)$, and you can plug in either of the two other points you know, namely $(0,5)$ and $(20,5)$, in order to solve for $a$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

1. A parabola's turning point occurs on its line of symmetry. (Why?)
2. $h(x)$ attains its minimum value when $(x-r)^2$ is minimised. (Why?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vertex form of a parabola, $f(x)=a(x-r)^2+s$ where $(r,s)$ are the vertex coordinates of the parabola.

But you would still then need to solve for the value of $a$, this could be done by using a known point, for example the point $(0,5)$.

Following these steps, you would get something along the lines of:

$f(x)=a(x-10)^2+1$, substitute vertex points for $r$ and $s$

$f(0)=a(-10)^2+1$

$f(0)=5$,known point

$5=100a+1$, use transitive property and simplify

$\frac{4}{25}=a$, solve for $a$

$f(x)= \frac{4}{25}(x-10)^2+1$, plug the value of $a$ into the vertex form